# Use Include Controller with dynamic path

Tags: csv, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I created a jmeter project with the included controller, which calls another jmx.
I need to dynamically construct the path using a csv in which there are the names of the jmx children to be called. For example C: performance $ {JmxName}.

I tried using the **CSV Data Set Config** but the included controller does not recognize the variable (*Error displayed: File "C:\performance\${JmxName}" not found for Include Controller "Include Controller"*)

do you have ideas on how to reach the goal?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller):

> This element **does not support** variables/functions in the filename field

So you will not be able to achieve this using Include Controller.

The options are in:

1. Include your "children" JMX scripts into the main JMX script and refer them via [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) where required. If you need to choose this or that scenario basing on the value of the variable from the CSV file - put the Module Controller's under the [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
2. If you cannot include children JMX scripts into the main one you can kick off them as separate processes using i.e. OS Process Sampler. The test results can be combined after the execution using i.e. [Merge Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/)